# Trying to get the remainder from modulus but having some troubles - in C

Tags: c, modulus

Updated with a created modulus function. However, while it does compile, after entering two numbers, it returns nothing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    double num1, num2, num3;
    printf("Enter two double numbers > ");
    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    scanf("%lf", &num2);
    num3 = num2;
    while (num3 > num1) {
        if (num3 > num1) {
        num3 = num3-num1;
        }
        else {
            printf("%.4lf float modulo %.4lf is %.4lf", num1, num2, num3);
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There've been several questions about that this week.  The `%` operator takes to integral operands; floating point does not work.  Look up `fmod()` and relatives in `<math.h>`.

Comment: use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) instead

Comment: Are the float values going to actually be integers stored in float format?

Comment: Yes, the prompt requires you to store them as doubles. I am guessing it was so that we would explicitly have to create our own modulus function, as we aren't allowed to use fmod. Which sucks, because I have no idea how to go about creating the function

Comment: @user1877731 See my answer. Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: crud, I think it went into an infinity loop...

Comment: there are several problems with the code: 1) the return code from calls to scanf() need to be checked to assure that the variable was actually set from the input. 2) the format strings should start with a ' ' to enable the skipping over of white space, including the newline char(s). 3) modulo does not work well with negative numbers, so the inputs should each be checked for greater than 0.0

Comment: the sequencing of the statements in the while code block will result in the loop being exited when the while condition fails.  However the print statement is inside the while loop.  suggest placing the printf() after the while loop and removing the 'if' as it is not needed.  Then while code block will only contain the num3 = num3-num1; statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, division is really just a shortcut form of subtraction, and a remainder is the part of the number that is left over when you divide. So consider repeatedly subtracting num2 from num1 until you have a number that is less than num2. That's your modulus. I'll leave the code up to you.

Example: 7 % 3:

```
7 - 3 = 4
4 - 3 = 1

1 < 3, so 7 % 3 = 1
```

Comment: This is actually much easier than what I was planning. I had originally thought of dividing num1 from num 2, and then subtracting the whole number from the result, to get the decimal, and then multiply that by the divisor again to get the remainder... but I had no idea how to get the decimal by itself without rounding, sine we aren't allowed to use math.h

Comment: Your solution to calculate `1000000000000 % 3` is to do about 333,333,333,333 subtractions?

Comment: I used a while loop, as of now, it is the best thing I can think of with the amount of time and lack of sleep I have had, as long as it works, I am okay with it.

Daniel, do you mind checking out the code, I updated it, now it compiles, but does nothing after entering the two numbers.

Comment: @chux For a homework assignment like this, I think this is a fine solution. No reason to get overly complicated

Comment: @user1877731 What do you mean it does nothing? This code should do _something_ and print out a result although you do have a subtle error that you should be able to figure out once you start seeing output. Are you sure that you recompiled? Also, you should **always** properly indent your code.

Comment: @user1877731 Oh, you're doing the mod backwards. You want to start by assigning num3 to num1, not num2. And then subtracting num2 from num3. But there is still a much more subtle error, that hopefully you will figure out.

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

Simply calculate the quotient, make the quotient a whole number and the calculate the modulus.  Depending on what definition of [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) you use, may want `if (x > 0)` instead of `if (q > 0)`

```
double fmod1877731(double x, double y) {
  double q = x/y;
  if (q > 0) q = floor(q);
  else q = ceil(q);
  return x - y*q;
}

void fmodtest(double x, double y) {
  double z0 = fmod(x,y);
  double z1 = fmod1877731(x,y);
  printf("x:% e y:% e z0:% 0.20e z1:% 0.20e\n", x,y,z0,z1);
}

int main(void) {
  fmodtest(10.0,3.0);
  fmodtest(10.0,-3.0);
  fmodtest(-10.0,3.0);
  fmodtest(-10.0,-3.0);
  fmodtest(10.0,1.23);
  fmodtest(10.0,15);
}
```